# PayPal Checkout (Orders v2) auto fill billing address

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am creating a PayPal Checkout button, is there any way to auto fill the billing address in the Debit or Credit Card form?

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8WMS.jpg)

My current code:

```
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                  return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '1'
          }
    }],
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this used to involve a `payer` object, and still works:

```
paypal.Buttons({
  enableStandardCardFields: true,
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      intent: 'CAPTURE',
      payer: {
        name: {
          given_name: "Firstname",
          surname: "Lastname"
        },
        address: {
          address_line_1: '123 ABC Street',
          address_line_2: 'Apt 2',
          admin_area_2: 'San Jose',
          admin_area_1: 'CA',
          postal_code: '95121',
          country_code: 'US'
        },
        email_address: "customer@domain.com",
        phone: {
          phone_type: "MOBILE",
          phone_number: {
            national_number: "14082508100"
          }
        }
      },
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            value: '15.00',
            currency_code: 'USD'
          },
          shipping: {
            address: {
              address_line_1: '2211 N First Street',
              address_line_2: 'Building 17',
              admin_area_2: 'San Jose',
              admin_area_1: 'CA',
              postal_code: '95131',
              country_code: 'US'
            }
          },
        }
      ]
    });
  }
}).render("body");
```

That `payer` parameter of the v2/checkout/orders API has been deprecated recently, though; seems the replacements will be in `payment_source.paypal`

Comment: I have tried but the example but it is for shipping address only not billing address, but thank you!

Comment: Verify your syntax is correct, since incorrect syntax will be ignored. The purchase_units shipping address gets used for billing but there is also a payer section for billing.

Comment: But we are selling digital product, we need to have "billing address" to be auto filled. If we display shipping address is incorrect, any solution?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context has a `shipping_preference` field